# Magento 2.3 collection factory not exist

Tags: magento2, collection, magento2.3, factory

I use magento 2.3 and I can't see collectionFactory created in generated folder or inject to any class.

ModelFactory can create normally.
There are my code:

Model file:

```
 <?php


namespace Lights\Magikfee\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
use Lights\Magikfee\Api\Data\MagikfeeInterface;

class Magikfee extends AbstractModel implements IdentityInterface, MagikfeeInterface
{
    /**
     * magikfee type
     */
    const FIXED = '2';
    const PERCENT = '1';

    /**
     * status
     */
    const ENABLE = '1';
    const DISABLED ='0';

    const CACHE_TAG = 'magikfee_model';

    /**
     * Magikfee constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb|null $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize model
     *
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Lights\Magikfee\Model\ResourceModel\Magikfee::class);
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
```

Resource model:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: thelight
 * Date: 1/19/19
 * Time: 11:23 PM
 */

namespace Lights\Magikfee\Model\ResourceModel;


class Magikfee extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    const TABLENAME ='magikfee';
    protected $_idFieldName = 'magikfee_id';

    /**
     * Magikfee constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
     * @param null|string $connectionName
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
        ?string $connectionName = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $connectionName);
    }

    /**
     * Resource initialization
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(self::TABLENAME, 'magikfee_id');
    }

}
```

Collection:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: thelight
 * Date: 1/19/19
 * Time: 11:24 PM
 */

namespace Lights\Magikfee\Model\ResourceModel\Magikfee;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * primary key
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'magikfee_id';

    /**
     * capture event magikfee_load_before
     * capture event magikfee_load_after
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'magikfee';

    /**
     * Collection constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface|null $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb|null $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }


    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Lights\Magikfee\Model\Magikfee::class, \Lights\Magikfee\Model\ResourceModel\Magikfee::class);
//        $this->_setIdFieldName($this->getResource()->getIdFieldName());
    }
}
```

I 'm highly appreciate with any help

Comment: I have exactly this issue